# Is there any equivalent available in SQL Server 2012+ for Excel's NORMSDIST?

Tags: sql, sql-server, normal-distribution

Is there any equivalent available in SQL Server 2012+ versions for Excel's `NORMSDIST` function without using any third party packages?

Comment: [Is this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10611737/2451726)?

Comment: @Arulkumar perfect. It would do. Thanks for the link. Put it as answer, I can mark it. Even it is not inbuilt it is solving the purpose.

Comment: If the linked post is solved your issue, let me close your post as duplicate. I recommended you to up vote the linked question and answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just write proper formula for density of normal distribution to calculate it:

```
DECLARE @arg REAL = 1.333;

SELECT (1/SQRT(2*PI()))*EXP(-POWER(@arg, 2)/2)
```